# change background color on active class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 2 clickeable classes that open two different divs.

Im trying to make so the active class keeps the hovering background as long its open.

tried a span but that didn't do the trick.
Any tips ? I created a fiddle for show http://jsfiddle.net/Qskxa/12/

Jquery code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.toggle_hide').hide();

    jQuery("#artistsbox li span").css('cursor', 'pointer').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.next("div").fadeToggle(200);
        $('.toggle_hide').not($this.next("div")).fadeOut(800);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (http://jsfiddle.net/Qskxa/14/):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.toggle_hide').hide();

    jQuery("#artistsbox li span").css('cursor', 'pointer').click(function() {
        $('#artistsbox li span.active').removeClass('active');
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.next("div").is(":hidden()")) $this.addClass('active');
        $this.next("div").fadeToggle(200);
        $('.toggle_hide').not($this.next("div")).fadeOut(800);
    });
});
```

Note that I changed the CSS and added the active class.

Comment: awsome solution. Thank you alot!

Comment: I use this as an answer , as it unactive when no active class is open.

Comment: One minor detail about the behavior, if you click on the active link, it will close/fade out the image, but the button is left in the active state once the mouse leaves the button.  I would expect that if I toggle off the image and mouse out, the button should be left in a inactive state.  The current solution can be modified by considering the case of "what happens if I click on an active button?"

Answer (score 1):

Simply create new css class active:

```
#artistsbox li span.active,
#artistsbox li span:hover{
background-color:#250109;
   -webkit-transition: background 0.1s linear;
        -moz-transition: background 0.1s linear;
        -ms-transition: background 0.1s linear;
        -o-transition: background 0.1s linear;
        transition: background 0.1s linear;

}
```

And update your click function so it will place that class on clicked element:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.toggle_hide').hide();

    jQuery("#artistsbox li span").css('cursor', 'pointer').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);        
        $("#artistsbox li span").removeClass("active");//remove active class from any other element that could be clicked previously
        $this.addClass("active");
        $this.next("div").fadeToggle(200);
        $('.toggle_hide').not($this.next("div")).fadeOut(800);
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Qskxa/13/)

Answer (score 1):

```
 http://jsfiddle.net/Praveen16oct90/Qskxa/15/
```

Note that i ve given id for each span for u to understand.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('.toggle_hide').hide();

jQuery("#d1").css('cursor', 'pointer').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.css("background-color","#250109");
     $("#d2").css("background-color"," #ffffec");
    $this.next("div").fadeToggle(200);
    $('.toggle_hide').not($this.next("div")).fadeOut(800);
});

jQuery("#d2").css('cursor', 'pointer').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.css("background-color","#250109");
    $("#d1").css("background-color"," #ffffec");
    $this.next("div").fadeToggle(200);
    $('.toggle_hide').not($this.next("div")).fadeOut(800);
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Try this -  http://jsfiddle.net/Qskxa/16/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.toggle_hide').hide();

  jQuery("#artistsbox li span").css('cursor', 'pointer').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var hasClass = $this.hasClass('active');
    $("#artistsbox li span").removeClass('active');
    if(!hasClass) $this.addClass('active');
    $this.next("div").fadeToggle(200);
    $('.toggle_hide').not($this.next("div")).fadeOut(800);
  });
});
```

*Note - change the css part as below

```
#artistsbox li span:hover, #artistsbox li span.active{
   background-color:#250109;
   -webkit-transition: background 0.1s linear;
   -moz-transition: background 0.1s linear;
   -ms-transition: background 0.1s linear;
   -o-transition: background 0.1s linear;
   transition: background 0.1s linear;
}
```